# c++ getter not returning changed value outside class

Tags: c++, class, setter, getter

I have 1 main class

```
class Vehicle{

   private:
      int fuel;
   public:
      int get_fuel(){ return this->fuel; }
      void set_fuel(int fuel){ this->fuel = fuel; }

};
```

also 1 subclass of Vehicle

```
class Car : public Vehicle{

    public:
       Car();

};

Car::Car(){

    set_fuel(500);

}
```

also my **main.cpp** file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argcv[]){

    Car c;

    cout << c.get_fuel() << endl; //500

    //set fuel to 200
    c.set_fuel(200);

    //print fuel again
    cout << c.get_fuel() << endl;//still 500

}
```

why after using the setter the value still remains the same after i use the getter?

Comment: You can use a debugger to follow the execution and see where it differs from what you expect.

Comment: @chris do you have any debugger in mind which could help us? We are using dev c++ as compiler

Comment: @fxuser: What platform are you working on? The two most common candidates for a debugger would be VS for windows, gdb for gcc (any platform)... there are others. On a different note, does the code you presented exhibit the behavior you wonder about? I don't think so.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to give a parameter the same name as something else in scope (a class member in this case).

Comment: Why is `vh.get_fuel()` 500 when you are setting it to 500 in the `Car` class constructor while here you use the `Vehicle` class for `vh`?

Comment: This code doesn't print what you say it does. Note that you're instantiating a `Vehicle`, not a `Car`.

Comment: I ran this and first thing that printed out was jiberish which suggests that the Car constructor wasn't called as you were expecting, also the second thing that printed out was 200 which suggests that it did change the value of fuel.

Comment: `Vehicle vh` was supposed to be `Car c`. fixed that sorry.

Comment: @cdhowie also used a different name for the class variable name but the same result

Comment: **Now run your code again but rename the private `fuel` to `_fuel`, just to test if the argument / property collision might be the problem.** Even if I've never seen such problem not occurring at compile time. And copy-paste the output here, not imaginary stuff.

Comment: @fxuser It wasn't the cause of the bug, no, but it's confusing and one shouldn't do that for readability.  The compiler got it right, but a human might not.  :)

Comment: It [works for me](http://ideone.com/bB6miO).

Comment: it was a compiler issue i guess.. after trying it with CodeBlocks it worked.. whatever.. thanks for the help guys

Comment: WOrking fine with gcc on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

**On VC++ 2012 your exact code works as expected.** Output is 500 and 200.

```
class Vehicle {
private:
    int _fuel;
public:
    Vehicle(){
        _fuel = 0;
    }
    int get_fuel(){
        return _fuel;
    }
    // I like chainable setters, unless they need to signal errors :)
    Vehicle& set_fuel(int fuel){
        _fuel = fuel;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    Car():Vehicle(){
        set_fuel(500);
    }
};

// using the code, in your main()
Car car;
std::cout << car.get_fuel() << std::endl; // 500
car.set_fuel(200);
std::cout << car.get_fuel() << std::endl; // actually 200
```

*This is a slightly modified version.* Place it in your .CPP file and try it. It can't not work!

**PS**: **Stop using properties that have the same name as arguments.** Always having to use `this->` is very not cool! *When you'll forget to use the `this->`, you'll see the bug of the century when you'll assign the value to itself and can't figure out what goes wrong.*